# Design: Chat rooms?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The Skeptics chat rooms don't have the Skeptics flavour:

[image]

This makes the logo almost vanish.

Perhaps this is intended for a later release? Or perhaps it is a bug? I wasn't sure. I tried refreshing / running on a different browser, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you'll get your own chat theme soon. We try to do this simultaneously with the site graduation, unfortunately time didn't permit it in this case.

Should happen today or tomorrow at the latest.

Comment: Still an issue.

Comment: Oops, I totally missed the logo part of your question (which now rereading is the main part of the post body). Sorry about that; will fix.